# Does Notepad++ support switching between tabs using numbers?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ supports either switching between the most recently used tabs or adjacent tabs (depending on the Notepad++ configuration). I was hoping to switch between tabs like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>, etc. just as in Google Chrome.

This functionality does not seem to be supported natively in Notepad++, but I was wondering if there is any plugin/addon that may support this. Or is there a different notepad application?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Notepad++ supports switching between tabs via the Contrl + NumberPad key combinations rather than the top level number keys.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did check settings but got lost with so many of them. I should have checked tabs. Thanks again. Very useful

Comment: Nice. I just tried this in Sublime Text and it supports it as well.

Comment: You can change these in the `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper`

Comment: @taco In Sublime you can also use Alt + Top-row number.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a standard keyboard you could use **Control+NumPad** key to switch between the first 9 tabs. 

You could also use **Control+PageUp** to switch to the Previous Tab and **Control+PageDown** to switch to the Next Tab.
*Source*: Go to Notepad++ > Click on View > Tab >

*Note*: *NumLock should be turned on.*

Also found this hidden feature during experimental shortcut search on Notepad++.
You can use **Control+Tab** to switch to the last used Tab. Also pressing and holding the **Control+Tab** will show you a list of all the files open in Notepad++. You could then keep pressing Tab to select which file you want to open(You could use the Up or Down Arrow keys to do the same).
**Control+Shift+Tab** takes you to the previous file name.

**Answer Bonus :)**: You could use **Control+Tab** to shift between tabs in *Google Chrome* too instead of using the Control+Number to switch tabs. **Control+Shift+Tab** will take you to the Previous Tab.